# How do I access objects in an array in angular by first element

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to bring up a list of scales when a user clicks a button in the scales-generator component. If the user clicks the "c" button, then only scales with "c" as the first element in the scalesList should come up. I looked into child routing and adding a new component with child route under the ScaleGeneratorComponent, but it hasn't worked - not sure if I am applying it correctly. So first of all, is this possible without child routing or is that the way to do this in angular?

```
//app.module.ts
  const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'scale-generator', component: ScaleGeneratorComponent},
  {path: 'modes', component: ModesPropertiesComponent},
  {path: 'scale-library', component: ScalesListComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/scale-library', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/scale-library', pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]
```

```
//scale.ts
export class Scale {

    constructor(public scaleKey: string,
                public scaleType: string,
                public scaleName: string,
                public scaleNotes: string
        ){
}
}
```

```
//scale-generator.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Scale } from '../scale';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-scale-generator',
  templateUrl: './scale-generator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scale-generator.component.css']
})
export class ScaleGeneratorComponent implements OnInit {
  
  //new array of guitar scales
  scalesList: Scale[] = [
    new Scale("c","major","C Ionian","C - D - E - F - G - A - B"),
    new Scale("c","major","C Lydian", "C - D - E - F# - G - A - B"),
    new Scale("f","major","F Ionian","F - G - A - Bb - C - D - E")
  ]

  

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {
      this.scalesList;
    }
    )
  }

}
```

```
//scale-generator.component.html
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a routerLink="scale-generator/:scalesList.scaleKey['c']" class="primary-btn">C</a>  
    </div>
   
</div>
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-hover">

            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Scale Name</th>
                    <th>Scale Notes</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let scale of scalesList">
                    
                    <td> {{ scale.scaleName }} </td>
                    <td> {{ scale.scaleNotes }} </td>
                    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: not immediately, sorry.

Comment: You know, I didn't get the problem completely too.

Comment: Sorry, the desired result is to click the c button shown in scale-generator.component.html and return scales of the scalesList from scale-generator.component.ts with the first element of "c". Currently, it does not do that.

Comment: @Craig, you are doing nothing when you make `this.route.paramMap.subscribe(() => {this.scalesList; //<--this makes "nothing"}`. Do you want to make some like: `subscribe(params => {this.scalesFilterd=this.scaleList(x=>x.scaleKey==params['id'])`. But in this case your path should be like `path: 'scale-generator/:id'` see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#route-parameters)

Comment: Thanks Eliseo, I am now getting errors that my scalesList is not callable along with TS7053 Element implicitly has an 'any' type. Since the scalesList is a list of Scale objects, I tried updating the object to 'any' but that did not take the error away.